# How to switch from CSV to JSON in D3? Github like chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, reactjs

I want to try [this](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063318) chart  ,but can't figure out how to switch from `CSV` to `JSON`.

I have this model (each object has id, createdAt, numberOfWords fields):

```
{ 
{ 
_id: someId, 
createdAt: 05/31/2016, 
numberOfWords: 0 < number < 1000
},
 ..., 
... 
}
```

- Should I change 
  `d3.csv`
  to 
  `d3.json`?
- Can I pass variable and not a file with data?
- Should I change code only inside d3.csv function or there are other places which are dependent from data representation?

I know that I definitely should change a function that is passed to rollup function? So...

- How should I change it properly?

Comment: You have to load in the correct file type, if the file is `.json`, you have to load it as `.json`, same with `csv`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have some JSON file like this:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "id1",
    "createdAt": "05/31/2016",
    "numberOfWords": 996
  },
  {
    "_id": "id2",
    "createdAt": "04/15/2016",
    "numberOfWords": 20
  },
  {
    "_id": "id3",
    "createdAt": "02/22/2015",
    "numberOfWords": 350
  }
]
```

You first should locate the date format in the example and change it to the format you are using, since it will be used to match the entries:

```
format = d3.time.format("%m/%d/%Y"); // changed to your time format
```

You also have to select the range, since the example shown doesn't include calendars that would fit your data (from 2016). So let's reduce it to 2 SVGs (2 years):

```
var svg = d3.select("body").selectAll("svg")
        .data(d3.range(2015, 2017)) // the range is 2015 and 2016
```

You can run the example now and see if it loads only those two calendars.

Ah, your color scale could be based on the amount of words, which you said is 0 to 1000, so also change this line:

```
var color = d3.scale.quantize()
              .domain([0, 1000]) // from 0 to 1000 words
              .range(...);
```

The range selects different colors declared in CSS in the example.

Since you have a JSON file, load it as JSON:

```
d3.json("yanis.json", function(error, json) {
    if (error) throw error;
```

Now you have to rearrange the data so it becomes a map indexed by the date. There are many ways to do that. You can use a `nest()` function as in the example, adapted to the properties in your file:

```
var data = d3.nest()
            .key(function(d) {
                return d.createdAt; // the key is your date
            })
            .rollup(function(d) {
                return {"numberOfWords": d[0].numberOfWords, "id": d[0]._id}; // return an object containing the data for each key
            })
            .map(json);
```

Each rectangle was previously created bound to a date string:

```
var rect = svg.selectAll(".day")
        .data(function(d) { return d3.time.days(new Date(d, 0, 1), new Date(d + 1, 0, 1)); })
        .enter().append("rect")
```

Now we will compare the date string bound to each rectangle and check if it exists in the `data` set. If a match is found, it will receive a CSS class which determines its fill color:

```
rect.filter(function(d) {
    return d in data;   // proceeds only for matching dates
}).attr("class", function(d) {
    return "day " + color(data[d].numberOfWords);  // apply a CSS class
})
```

Finally you should also change the `title` selection, so the tooltip will show something significant, like number of words or id:

```
.select("title")
    .text(function(d) { 
        return d + ": " + data[d].numberOfWords + " words"; 
    });
```

And yes, you can simply assign the whole JSON file to a variable instead of loading it, if you wish. Here's a [working example](https://jsfiddle.net/helderdarocha/mfnqz8q8/1/):

Answer (score 1):

D3 provides a method for json analogous to the csv method used in the calendar example.
https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/Requests